# How do I create a dynamic query that filters on month and day?

Tags: 7, database

I want to get the list of the nodes, whose content type is *Donors*, where the date in the field_data_field_donor_date_of_birth matches today (except the year).

How can I achieve it using a dynamic query or the `EntityFieldQuery` class?

This is the code I tried so far.

```
$query = db_select('node', 'node');
$query->fields('node', ['nid','title'])
  ->condition('node.status', 1)
  ->condition('node.type', 'CONTENT_TYPE_DONOR');

$query->innerJoin('field_data_field_donor_date_of_birth', 
 'field_donor_date_of_birth'
, 'field_donor_date_of_birth.entity_id = node.nid');
$query->condition('field_donor_date_of_birth.field_donor_date_of_birth_value', $birth_date, '=');

$result = $query->execute();
```

Comment: Since the question is about code to write, you should show the code you wrote so far. If there is anything you don't understand in the described task, you need to clearly state what that is.

Comment: The question is also missing details. It's asking how to get the list of users whose birthday is today, but it doesn't say where the birthday is stored. (I assume it's an entity field, but the question doesn't say which field that is exactly.)

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Thanks. I have added code for demonstration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to query the date by using a where clause instead of condition.
Example, replace

```
 $query->condition('field_donor_date_of_birth.field_donor_date_of_birth_value', $birth_date, '=');
```

with

```
$time = format_date(time(), 'custom', 'm-d');
$query->where("DATE_FORMAT(field_donor_date_of_birth.field_donor_date_of_birth_value, '%m-%d') = '$time'");
```